# What are good resources (other than Apple) to understand certificates, code signing, provisioning and related subjects?

Tags: ios, certificate, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I suffer from the **complete and utter failure** to grasp the concepts of code signing, provisioning, and all related subjects to distributing iOS apps. This is despite the fact that I have been developing in Xcode for 2 years and have successfully launched 2 apps in the App Store - I just don't get it.

I have tried to read through Apple's documentation, but either I am too obtuse or the documentation is not good enough to give me any meaningful understanding of the process.

I am asking for some alternative blog posts, websites, articles, infographics, charts, diagrams, **anything** that has helped others get a better understanding of these crucial concepts.

Posts I have read on SO seem to treat the symptoms, not the problem.

Comment: Possible (not quite) Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866647/the-relationship-between-provisioning-profiles-certificates-app-ids-and-keys/9866728#9866728

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I've found, when I needed to understand the process, this post did it..!

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this: This should help you get started

http://seventhsoulmountain.blogspot.com/2013/09/ios-code-sign-in-complete-walkthrough.html